# Turn multiple columns in excel into 1 column with unique value

Tags: excel, csv

I have a list of questions as series of columns in excel with around 10,000 rows.  Yes or No is denoted by a 0 or 1 and only 1 question can be selected for any give row.  What I'd like to do is take all these columns and merge them into 1 column where the value of each question is assign to a number instead.  So for instance I have:

```
   Q1            Q2         Q3           Q4           Q5 
   0             1          0            0            0  
   0             0          0            1            0  
   0             0          1            0            0  
   0             1          0            0            0  
   1             0          0            0            0
```

So instead I'd like to assign each question to a value like

Q1 = 1
Q2 = 2
Q3 = 3
Q4 = 4
Q5 = 5

and them merge it into one column like:

```
Questions
    2
    4
    3
    1
```

Is there a decently simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Match function:

```
=MATCH(1,B2:F2,0)
```

[image]

Comment: But what if there are 10,000 rows?  I dont want to have to manually match them all

Comment: You don't you just drag or copy the cell down the length. The reference will automatically change. @Mr.BigglesWorth